# google apps script - batch setValues() on Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting, google-apps

In order to optimize my code, I'm trying to do the batch updates.  Instead of calling setValues() on the loop, I want to store the data in an array, then do an setValues() once after the loop.  However, I can't make it work:

```
var tempValuesArr= [];
var ctr = 0;

for ....{

  //there is only one row needed for every second sheet, get the data at the 2nd 
  //row with 6 columns
  var secondSheetRange = secondSheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 6);  
  tempValuesArr.push(secondSheetRange.getValues());
  ctr++;
}

//finally, copy these tempValues at another sheet, starting at second row
var anotherSheetRange = anotherSheet.getRange(2, 1, ctr, 6);
anotherSheetRange .setValues(tempValuesArr);
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

> Incorrect range width, was 1 but should be 6

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are pushing a 2d array ( `[[CellA2, CellB2], [CellA3, CellB3]]` ) into a 1d array ( `[]` ), leaving you with a 3d array ( `[[[CellA2, CellB2], [CellA3, CellB3]]]` ).

To use setvalues you need a 2d ( `[[CellA2, CellB2], [CellA3, CellB3]]`- 2 rows OR `[[CellA2, CellB2]]`- 1 row ) array of values.

Try this, it will only push the first 1d array ( `[CellA2, CellB2, CellC2]` ) from the range into the empty array you created at the start. More information [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp).

```
tempValuesArr.push(secondSheetRange.getValues()[0])
```

Comment: does this works only when I'm retrieving only one row from the second sheet?  When I'm trying multiple rows retrieval on second sheet, it's giving me an error again.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `.getValues()[0]` will only return the first row in an array (I've edited my answer to make it a bit clearer). If you want to add more than one row from a single sheet you'll need to either select duplicate the existing `getRange` / `getValues()[0]` bits for each row, or get the values for several cells and either push rows you want one by one or use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
tempValuesArr.push(secondSheetRange.getValues()[0]);
```

secondSheetRange.getValues() returns a two-dimensional array where are you require only a single row array

Comment: does this works only when I'm retrieving only one row from the second sheet?  When I'm trying multiple rows retrieval on second sheet, it's giving me an error again.  Thanks in advance!